# After java update my ant scripts doesnt work

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

After I updated java from 8u20 to 8u25 my ant scripts in Eclipse stopped working. I got errror "file not found" in deploying tasks. Here is linie that fails:

```
<deploy url="${tomcat}" path="${package}" username="${login}" password="${pwd}" war="file:dist/app.war" />
```

File is on its place.

Comment: "deploy" is not a standard ANT task. "file not found" also not a typical generic ANT task message I must guess it refers to the location of the war file. Does the file "dist/app.war" exist?

Comment: Yes it extist, and everything worked before java update.

Comment: Run ant with -verbose, maybe there comes a helpful stacktrace

Comment: Ok i found solution, in JRE ANT options it must be set "Run in separate enviroment"